# How do I say "that would be a bit interesting"?

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras

How would I express the feeling when we're intrigued by something or a bit curious about how something would play out and we say something along the lines of "Hmm, that would be a bit interesting"?

Cuando lo digo en español me siento que estoy diciendo que "eso no me interesa". Decir "Hmm, es poco interesante." no tiene el mismo sentimiento de lo que quiero decir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That reminds me of something we say to the kids when they ask if we are there yet when driving somewhere:

> *Falta poco para llegar.* (We're almost arriving.)
>   *Falta un poco para llegar.* (They'll have to wait a bit more.)

Not exactly the same case as yours, but note that your are translating "a bit" (an expression that increases the importance of what is expressed, as in my second example) as "poco" (and hence decrementing the importance of what is expressed, as in my first example). Nonetheless, you cannot use "un poco" in your example, so let's move to other options:

> *Eso parece [algo] interesante.* (That seems [a bit] interesting.)
>   *Eso podría ser interesante.* (That could be interesting.)

The idea to convey is that you could be intrigued by that, but you are still not sure, hence the use of *parecer* or the conditional *podría*.

Comment: Could you make it a bit clearer what the difference is between the two driving examples?  That is, in which one are you the closest to your destination?  Also, I think you could strengthen this great answer by explaining what *poco* (without *un*) means, e.g. *Tengo pocos recursos (I have scanty/limited resources); nos queda poca agua por lo que tenemos que conservarla (we have little water left, so we have to conserve)*.

Comment: @aparente001 your examples are perfectly valid. "Poco" means little, limited... The trick is that "un poco" gives a positive feeling to the sentence. If you say "nos queda una poca de agua" you're saying that "you still have some water left". So in the driving examples, the use of "poco" is straightforward, while the use of "un poco" implies that there's still some way to go.

Comment: Pero debes decir "nos queda _un poco_ de agua".

Comment: @matthiasdenu tal vez me haya dejado llevar por un andalucismo... :-)

Comment: I'll let you off this one time ;-) Pero está bien. Español no es mi primero idioma. Aun no aprendí todos los coloquialismos.